# Easy way to deploy static pages with Google Apps authentication

Tags: web-hosting, g-suite

I'm looking for an easy way to host my small company's internal docs.  We already use Google Apps for much of our IT, so it would be low-maintenance if we could authenticate users to visit these docs by their accounts in our domain.  The docs are version-controlled along with our code, and so I want to be able to script deployment, when the docs are edited.  I also don't want to invest a whole lot of time into solutions that might take non-trivial development effort.  This is mostly a convenience thing I'm going for.

I checked out Google Sites, but it doesn't seem to support uploading of content.  I checked out Google Drive, but it doesn't seem to support authentication.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a ready-made answer, so I made my own solution using Google AppEngine.  It seems like a reasonably common problem, so I posted it to Bitbucket as an open source project called [Docserver](https://bitbucket.org/acjohnson55/docserver).  Hopefully someone else finds it helpful, or adds something useful to it.